# Using fill() on objects with for loop

Tags: object, for-loop, processing, fill, processing.js

I'm creating a game in Processing (JavaScript) which allows you to color a grid of rectangles as they become highlighted one by one.

I'm trying to color an array of objects using a for loop and the fill() function, but when I use it, it colors not only colors the current rectangle in the array (which would be correct), but also all previous rectangles. I want it to only color the current rectangle.

```
void setup () {
  size (1200, 700);
  background (255, 255, 255);
  smooth();
  rect = new Rectangle [count]; //creates a grid of possible rectangles, based on the dimensions of the screen
  for (int i = 0; i<= (count-1); i++) {
    fill (255, 255, 255);
    ypos = ypos + heigh;
    if (ypos >= 700) {
      ypos = 0;
      xpos = xpos + wid;
    }
    rect[i] = new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, wid, heigh, redPressed, greenPressed, yellowPressed, bluePressed, blackPressed);
  }
  int now = millis();
}

void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i < control; i++) {
    if (keyPressed) { //detects if key is pressed and colors the current rectangle that way
      if (key == 'r' ||key == 'R') {
        fill (255, 0, 0);
      }
      if (key == 'g' ||key == 'G') {
        fill (0, 255, 0);
      }
      if (key == 'y' || key == 'Y') {
        fill (255, 255, 0);
      }
      if (key == 'b' || key == 'B') {
        fill (0, 0, 255);
      }
      if (key == 'k' || key == 'K') {
        fill (0, 0, 0);
      }
    }
    stroke (0, 0, 0);
    rect (rect[i].xpos, rect[i].ypos, rect[i].xdim, rect[i].ydim); //draws the current rectangle, moving through the grid
  }
  if (millis() - now >= wait) { //causes a 1 second delay between rectangles
    now = millis();
    control++;
    if (control > (count-1)) {
      control = (count-1);
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the 'control' variable in for-loop? It looks like the draw function could be drawing multiple rectangles since it's in the for-loop. Also, how do you determine the "current rectangle" in the array?

Comment: @Bergi the control variable forces a 1-second delay between the drawing of each rectangle.  It increases by 1 every 1 second. And by "current rectangle" I mean whatever value "i" is in the for-loop. So when i = 1, the current triangle is rect[1].

Comment: You meant to ping @AmirS

Comment: @AmirS the control variable forces a 1-second delay between the drawing of each rectangle. It increases by 1 every 1 second. And by "current rectangle" I mean whatever value "i" is in the for-loop. So when i = 1, the current triangle is rect[1].

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can't run this code because you haven't posted your `Rectangle` class or your `control`, 'count', 'xpos', 'ypos', `wid`, `heigh`, `redPressed`, `greenPressed`, `yellowPressed`, `bluePressed`, or `blackPressed` variables. variables. If you want help, you have to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can actually run.

Secondly, you're doing some weird things here: why are you looping through your `Rectangle` array if you only want to draw one of them at a time? Why are you manually causing a wait instead of just setting the framerate?

Instead of looping through your rectangles every time `draw()` is called, keep track of the **index** and directly access it. Instead of doing the waiting yourself, just set the framerate:

```
int index = 0;
Rectange[] rect;

void setup () {
  size (1200, 700);
  background (255, 255, 255);
  smooth();
  rect = new Rectangle [count]; //creates a grid of possible rectangles, based on the dimensions of the screen
  for (int i = 0; i<= (count-1); i++) {
    fill (255, 255, 255);
    ypos = ypos + heigh;
    if (ypos >= 700) {
      ypos = 0;
      xpos = xpos + wid;
    }
    rect[i] = new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, wid, heigh, redPressed, greenPressed, yellowPressed, bluePressed, blackPressed);
  }
  int now = millis();
  frameRate(1);
}

void draw() {

  if (keyPressed) { //detects if key is pressed and colors the current rectangle that way
    if (key == 'r' ||key == 'R') {
      fill (255, 0, 0);
    }
    if (key == 'g' ||key == 'G') {
      fill (0, 255, 0);
    }
    if (key == 'y' || key == 'Y') {
      fill (255, 255, 0);
    }
    if (key == 'b' || key == 'B') {
      fill (0, 0, 255);
    }
    if (key == 'k' || key == 'K') {
      fill (0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  stroke (0, 0, 0);
  rect (rect[index].xpos, rect[index].ypos, rect[index].xdim, rect[index].ydim);  
  index++;
  if (index >= rect.length) {
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

Please make an effort to post an MCVE next time.